# How to restrict access to specific classes in C#?

Tags: c#, proxy, internal

I have 2 projects, a website and a proxy library (dll)

Proxy Project has..

```
public class Client
{
}

public class Proxy
{
    public Client GetClient()
    {
        return new Client();
    }
}
```

How can I prevent the website from creating a new instance of Client but allow it to create an instance of Proxy, and still run GetClient?

Comment: do you need to have only one instance of the Client class all the time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change Client to:

```
internal class Client
{
}
```

That way the website project can't even see the Client class, or you could do:

```
public class Client
{
   internal Client()
   {

   }
}
```

That way the website can see it and interact with it, but not actually construct an instance.

Comment: That is what I was looking for, didn't think about making the constructors internal

Comment: @csharpdev No worries, these sorts of simple solutions escape everyone from time to time!

Comment: usually I never use internal but since im working in a team, many people are not using the classes we created for them ;)  .. now they will have to use it!

Comment: @csharpdev If people are mucking with your internal classes just stick `[Obsolete(IsError=true,ErrorMessage="Oy!")]` On them, and publish it.

Comment: @asawyer aha, +1 for the creative way at passively aggressively shouting at colleagues via code.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a public interface `IProxy`.  Ensure that it has all aspects of `Proxy` that you want publicly exposed.
2. Have `Proxy` implement `IProxy`.
3. Make `Proxy` `internal` (or even private, and a nested class of `Client`, if applicable).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to be able to create a new instance of Client, consider either making Client static or utilizing the Singleton pattern

Answer (score 1):

You can use the singleton pattern, or declare an `internal` constructor in your Client class